# I'm having trouble with my binary to decimal converter

Tags: vb.net

When I put in a binary number it gives me more than one result in messagebox.show.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim s As String
    Dim a, b, c As Long
    a = CLng(Val(TxtBoxInput.Text))
    s = TxtBoxInput.Text
    TxtBoxInput.Clear()

    For i = 1 To Len(s) Step 1
        b = CLng(Mid(s, i, 1))
        c = Len(s) - i
        b = CLng(Val(b) * (2 ^ c))
        TxtBoxInput.Text = CStr(MessageBox.Show(CStr(Val(TxtBoxInput.Text) + b)))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this WinForms?  WPF?  ASP.NET?  MVC?

Comment: Why are you trying to assign a `MessageBox` to a `TextBox`?

Comment: @Tim It makes some degree of sense, the `MessageBox.Show` method returns a value indicating the result of the MessageBox.

Answer (score 2):

You would use the [MsgBox Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.msgbox%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It is uncertain from your example where the result is that you are wanting to show.

```
MsgBox("Information Here", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "MyTitle")
```

---

*Edit based on Comments*

Put your MessageBox outside of your loop something like this:

```
Dim s, temp As String
Dim a, b, c As Long

a = CLng(Val(TxtBoxInput.Text))
s = TxtBoxInput.Text
TxtBoxInput.Clear()
For i = 1 To Len(s) Step 1
    b = CLng(Mid(s, i, 1))
    c = Len(s) - i
    b = CLng(Val(b) * (2 ^ c))
    temp = CStr(Val(temp) + b)
 Next i

MessageBox.Show(temp)
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for [MessageBox.Show Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx), based on his question.

Comment: when I input a binary number it gives me more than one result in messagebox? I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Your MessageBox is in your loop therefore it is going to trigger multiple times

Comment: @Tim His question did not have that in it when I answered it.

Comment: @MarkHall - I'm not trying to be nitpicky, but...shouldn't the value for MessageBox be `CStr(Val(TxtBoxInput.Text))` - no `+ b`? :)

Comment: @Tim I just took his equation that he was displaying in his TextBox and transferred it over to the MessageBox.Show method. I just saw that I left his old code in, I will remove and add a temp variable. As I said it is uncertain exactly what he is wanting to do.

Comment: @MarkHall - Yeah, OP's question isn't entirely clear.  Like I said - didn't want to seem nitpicky, and I've seen you on SO and know you know what you're talking about :)  I was just worried OP would do a cut and paste and still wonder why his output wasn't what (I think) he wants.

Comment: Thanks guys I figured it out. :)

Comment: Oh and thanks for nothing Tim. I'm still learning so I'm allowed to make mistakes.

Comment: @user2297341 We all are allowed to make mistakes, Tim was good enough to call my attention to a couple that I made trying to answer your question in order to make sure that the answer was clear and what you were needing.

Comment: I didn't read all of the comments, but is there a reason you're recommending `MsgBox` over `MessageBox.Show`? He already has `MessageBox.Show` in his original code, right?

Comment: I know that and I appreciated but I didn't the fact that he was referring to me as OP.

Comment: @CodyGray No specific reason just when I answered the question, his code did not have MessageBox.Show in it, so I used the MsgBox Method. I added the MessageBox.Show Method later in my Edit.

Comment: @user2297341 [OP](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/whats-stackexchange-ese-for-op) just means originating poster, there is nothing detrimental about it.

Comment: @user2297341 - As Mark indicated, nothing I wrote was meant or intended to be detrimental or insulting.  If it came across that way I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim s As String
Dim a, b, c As Long
a = CLng(Val(TxtBoxInput.Text))
s = TxtBoxInput.Text
TxtBoxInput.Clear()

For i = 1 To Len(s) Step 1
    b = CLng(Mid(s, i, 1))
    c = Len(s) - i
    b = CLng(Val(b) * (2 ^ c))
    TxtBoxInput.Text = CStr(Val(TxtBoxInput.Text) + b)
Next i
```

MSGBOX(TXTBOXINPUT)